# jquery live search callback function

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-callback, livesearch

This plugin uses regular expression to sort content, in real-time, based on your search input.

I've created few buttons for search like this:

```
    <input id="searchbox" type="text" class="searchFilter" onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value='Keyword(s)'" onfocus="this.value==this.defaultValue?this.value='':null" value="Keyword(s)" name="keyword">

        <a href="#" class="search-btn" data-search="text1 ">search 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="search-btn" data-search="intro ">search 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="search-reset">reset</a>
```

and a snippet of the code :

```
       $(".search-btn").on("click", function(){
       $("#searchbox").val( $(this).data("search") );
       $('.searchFilter').keyup();
       });             

       $(".search-reset").on("click", function(){
       $("#searchbox").val( "");
       $('.searchFilter').keyup();
   });
```

What I want to do is when "Search 1" is clicked to append a class called let's say "visible-elements" to all the elements which are visible after that search is performed  and after call a function.

This is a good example of what I'm trying to achieve  applied to another search plugin but it shows the concept of  what I'm trying to do :

```
$('input#id_search').quicksearch('div.member', {
show: function () {
$(this).addClass('visible-elements');
 },
hide: function() {
$(this).removeClass('visible-elements');
},
onAfter: function() {
$container.isotope({ filter: 'visible-elements'});
}
});
```

The issue is that I don't know how to make this work in my actual structure, any suggestions are welcome.

here is a  working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/V2pQf/17/) example.

here is the testing [website](http://v2.letsplayibiza.com/elements/)